# IIS 6 not logging

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6

i have a windows 2003 (64bit) as a IIS server.

The IIS was logging my virtual servers but lately i noticed that it does not log anymore.
1. i checked the "root" logging it its enabled
2. I checked all the virtual guests if it;s enabled.
3. i checked with the metadata explorer for logtype (its 1), and there are no (dontlog) entryes
4. I rebooted the server.
5. The Event Log doest not say anything..

i dont know what to look anymore..any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Logging is usually very consistent and 'just works'.  Some possible things to check would be the permissions on the folder just in case IIS doesn't have permissions to write (although IIRC it uses SYSTEM so that's doubtful).  Confirm that the path to the logs is still correct, and you may want to just turn off the logging, apply, and turn it on again to make sure that it's applied correctly (IIS doesn't really need that per se, but it's something to do to be extra sure).

Comment: the permisions are ok, local admin and system. I also unchecked and checked again the settings. The paths are OK, double checked also in metabase explorer. but no logging...

Comment: Try process monitor from www.sysinternals.com.  That will let you know if it's attempting to write it somewhere else.